# Conga-Docusign Integration not working

Tags: docusignapi

I've got a really simple conga button that should be auto-sending with 1 click a Docusign envelope from Salesforce.  I get no errors, but no Docusign envelope never gets emailed.

Any idea what is wrong with this button code?

```
https://www.appextremes.com/apps/Conga/Composer.aspx? 
sessionId={!API.Session_ID} 
&serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_80} 
&id={!Opportunity.Id} 
&TemplateID=a1Z4000000067pT 
&DocuSignR1ID=003f000000Ax1Dc 
&DocuSignR1Role=Legal+Approver 
&DocuSignR1Type=Approver 
&DocuSignR1RoutingOrder=1 
&DS7=17
```

If I take out the DS7 parameter, the auto-send is turned off, and everything works manually just fine.  But leaving in the DS7 parameter, the email never gets sent.

Comment: As Kim has mentioned in her answer, have you set the DS7 parameter to 7 and created a *LegalApprover* role through the DocuSign Console?

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you set the **DS7** parameter value to **7** ?  (From http://knowledge.congasphere.com/congakb/ext/kb494-ds7-parameter -- "Background Mode is enabled and the merged document is attached to a DocuSign Envelope")

Also, within the (DocuSign) ***Envelope Settings*** screen, is "LegalApprover" defined as one of the roles?  From http://knowledge.congasphere.com/congakb/ext/kb21-conga-docusign-integration-parameters -- "[DocuSignR1Role requires] a valid DocuSign Role Name, as defined in Envelope Settings."

**UPDATE - more info about Role name (in [DocuSign] Envelope Settings):**

A little more info about my earlier comment re the value of **DocuSignR1Role** needing to match one of the DocuSign Role names you've defined for you DocuSign for Salesforce app.  To view the DocuSign role names that are defined in Salesforce, go to **DocuSign Admin** >> and then navigate to **Envelopes** -- within that page, you'll see a section called **Recipient Role Settings**:

[image: DfS Envelope Settings screen]

Within the **Recipient Role Settings** section, you'll see a list of Role Names:

[image: DfS Recipient Role Names]

This list is customizable (in the screenshot above, I've expanded the default 4-recipient-roles to 7 roles), but keep in mind that the role list will apply to all DocuSign envelopes you send via DocuSign for Salesforce in the current Salesforce org -- so you'll likely want to use generic values (ex: Signer 1, Signer 2, etc.) instead of envelope/template-specific values (ex: Insured, Applicant, etc.).

In your custom button code, you'll want to make sure that the value you set for the **DocuSignR1Role** parameter appears in this list. Choose the Role Name value in the list whose sequence in the list corresponds to the number that you're using in the Anchor Text property of that recipient's tags. For example:

- If your envelope uses the number '1' in the Anchor Text properties for the recipient's tags, then you'd specify **DocuSignR1Role=Signer 1** (i.e., the ***first*** value in the Recipient Roles list).
- If your envelope uses the number '2' in the Anchor Text properties for the recipient's tags, then you'd specify **DocuSignR1Role=Signer 2** (i.e., the ***second*** value in the Recipient Roles list).
- If your envelope uses the number '3' in the Anchor Text properties for the recipient's tags, then you'd specify **DocuSignR1Role=Signer 3** (i.e., the ***third*** value in the Recipient Roles list).
- Etc., etc., etc.